# saving excel file in a mac with newline recognizable by linux

Tags: linux, macos, excel

I find myself doing this very often.

Open a csv file in a mac, save it as a csv on my mac, transfering the file via scp to linux, then scping the file back to linux, and then [having to convert the file new lines to linux format](http://thushw.blogspot.com/2011/07/mac-microsoft-excel-newlines-r-n.html) once in linux.

Is there a way to avoid the 'converting new lines to linux format from mac step'?  It's getting quite annoying to have to do this step every time i move files back and forth.

Comment: The old `ftp`, File Transfer Protocol, does this conversion automatically.

Comment: @mouviciel that's nice, anyway to do ftp transfer command line in mac?  i.e., the equivalent to scp <local_mac_fullname> <myserveraddress>:<fullname_of_file>?  For several reasons it's not convenient for me to use ftp clients like fugu, and/or having to connect to the server to transfer the files, one ftp transfer command in unix (scp style) would be the most convenient but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, ftp is interactive. An alternative would be to define a function performing both conversion and transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a bash function and use it in place of `scp`:

```
csvtransfer() {
  csvfile="$1"
  perl -i -ne 's/([^\r])\r/$1\n/g; s/\r//g; print;'  "$csvfile"
  scp <options> "$csvfile"
}
```